# What should I do if I want to add clearInterval in diferent methods?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, setinterval, nuxt.js, clearinterval

I've `moveMarker` methods with `setInterval` to making my Marker in mapbox-gl is moving along my Routes Line and I've play button to trigger this function . My question is , what should I do if I want to create pause button with clearInterval?

I've tried create function to `clearInterval` in `moveMarker` but doesn't work

this is my function to move the marker :

```
moveMarker () {
    const moveCoordinate = []
    const loop = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.index + 1 === (this.coordinates.length - 1)) {
        clearInterval(loop)
      }
      for (let index = 0; index < moveCoordinate.length; index++) {
        moveCoordinate[index].remove()
      }
      this.map.panTo(this.coordinates[this.index])
      const lat = this.coordinates[this.index][0]
      const lng = this.coordinates[this.index][1]
      const newMarker = new mapboxgl.LngLat(lat, lng)
      console.log('new', newMarker)
      const markerMapbox = new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat(newMarker)
        .addTo(this.map)
      moveCoordinate.push(markerMapbox)
      this.index++
    }, 1000)
  },
```

and this is stop function :

```
stop () {
    clearInterval(this.moveMarker)
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you should store you interval in data property, to have access to it in the `stop` method. Then in `stop` method just call `clearInterval` with stored `interval`:

```
export default {
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      interval: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    moveMarker () {
      const moveCoordinate = []
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.index + 1 === (this.coordinates.length - 1)) {
          clearInterval(this.interval)
        }
        for (let index = 0; index < moveCoordinate.length; index++) {
          moveCoordinate[index].remove()
        }
        this.map.panTo(this.coordinates[this.index])
        const lat = this.coordinates[this.index][0]
        const lng = this.coordinates[this.index][1]
        const newMarker = new mapboxgl.LngLat(lat, lng)
        console.log('new', newMarker)
        const markerMapbox = new mapboxgl.Marker()
          .setLngLat(newMarker)
          .addTo(this.map)
        moveCoordinate.push(markerMapbox)
        this.index++
      }, 1000)
    },
    stop() {
      clearInterval(this.interval)
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: okay thats work , thanks . btw when i click again the button i've got the marker is resume the coordinate but create another marker . do yo know how to fix it?

Comment: So you want to reset coordinates?

Comment: i want if click the stop function and then click button play , the movemarker still works without adding new marker on it

Answer (score 0):

Calling `clearInterval` on the `moveMarker` method isn't going to do anything. You need to save the interval id somewhere that `stop` can access it.

e.g. Inside `moveMarker`:

```js
this.intervalId = loop
```

Then:

```js
stop () {
   clearInterval(this.intervalId)
}
```

There's no need to add `intervalId` to your `data` as you don't need it to be reactive.